SRAM Rival Hydraulic Brake - Bleeding issues
After 5000km of perfect performance my rear brake started to fade so I decided to bleed it.
I have bled many hydraulic systems before (mostly MTB) with no issues.
However the SRAM Rival setup has been tough.
When I removed the bleed port screw on the caliper (not the lever) it looked like a tiny o-ring had disintegrated.  I attempted to bleed the system without the o-ring and the port kept leaking air - so whenever I tried to pressurise the system air bubble kept appearing.
So I ordered some replacement o-rings and inserted one into the bleed port (as it did not look possible to install the o-ring onto the bleed port screw).  The port still kept leaking air and I could not pressurise the system.  Also dot fluid was coming out the bleed port even with the syringe attached.
Has anyone else had this problem?
Does the caliper need an o-ring on the bleed port screw or inbetween the rear bleed port and the bleed port screw?
What am I missing here?!
Thanks in advance if you can help :)
